# Lemon juice and carbonic acid reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I was doing a chemistry project to see if the pH of a carbonated solution effects the time taken for it to settle after being disrupted, and I am trying to map out the reaction when the components are combined.

I was able to figure out a few, but I got stuck on carbonic acid and lemon juice.  For some reason, I was getting ethane as a by product of the reaction, and I'm sure that's not right.  Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

the formula is $\ce{H2CO3 + C6H8O7}$

Comment: I'm assuming $\ce{C6H8O7}$ is citric acid. Acid + acid does not necessarily do anything productive.

Comment: if you're getting ethane there is something wrong here.  are you sure it is lemon juice?

Comment: You should show what have you done...In my opinion there are no reactions between these two acid. When you make a lemonade you mix lemon juice that has a bit of citric acid with sparkling water that has carbonic acid  and you don't smell ethane.

Comment: Would you mind to explain how you determined that ethane was produced?

Answer (score 1):

These two weak acids have similar disassociation constants in water.  A low Ka indicates a relatively small number of acid molecules will form an anion stabilized by water.  Two weak acids with similar disassociation constants will coexist in a solution without interacting.  If two weak acids have very different Ka then there can be a reaction.  In this case nothing would happen.   For more generalized information search for mixture of weak acids.

> Carbonic Acid

$$\ce{H2CO3 + H2O <=> HCO3- + H3O+}$$
$$K_a = 4.3 \times 10^{-7} = \frac{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{HCO3^-}]}{[\ce{H2CO3}]}$$

> Citric Acid

$$\ce{H3C6H5O7 + H2O <=> H2C6H5O7- + H3O+}$$
$$K_a = 1.8 \times 10^{-6}  = \frac{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{H2C6H5O7^-}]}{[\ce{H3C6H5O7}]}$$

Answer (score 0):

By Le Chatelier's principle ,a new equilibrium will be formed for the H3O+ concentration , since H2CO3 has the lower dissociation constant.H3O+ concentration and therefore the pH will lie somewhere between the two acids